# Why are my nested comments getting bigger?

Tags: html, css, web, nested

Here on this page:

http://www.nickhodges.com/post/More-on-FreeAndNil.aspx#comment

if you scroll down, you'll notice that the nested comments are getting bigger.   I'm not that smart on CSS, but obviously some element is building on itself.

Any ideas on what is causing this or how I might start tracking it down?

Comment: You know you have something like a hundred different divs all with the same ids - `commentheader`, `commentmain`, `commentfooter`, `container-comment`

Comment: `.comment` has a `font-size: 110%` - is it possible that that is stacking to the nested comments?

Comment: I like how it is, like the people are arguing and getting louder and louder each post.  A screaming match in the last few replies.

Comment: :-)  It does look like a screaming match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in this file: http://www.nickhodges.com/themes/BlueHorizon/css.axd?name=style2.5.0.6.css

Your `comment` class has `font-size:110%;` property on it.

Comment: That was exactly it.  I should have been able to figure that out. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix would be to create a new CSS rule:

```
.comment .comment {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Although cleaning up the code would be even better.